# On multi-site CiviCRM, are mailings supposed to be separated per-domain?

Tags: multisite, civimail

According to the CiviCRM wiki [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=86213708), under "Functional Separation in Multisite", mailings are listed as separated by domain.  However, when my users access the "Scheduled and Sent Mailings", they see mailings from all domains.  I know that civicrm_mailing has a field domain_id.  Is there something I need to do to enforce this separation?  Or am I just misreading the wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since fixed this bug, with funding from Healthcare-NOW and significant assistance from the dev team at the Autralian Green Party: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16981

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug. Please log an issue on https://issues.civicrm.org.

Comment: FWIW - after you said this, I dug into the code.  I learned that Civi core doesn't call the aclGroup hook on the "Find Mailings" page (I neglected to mention that I'm using the Fuzion multisite extension).  I think I just got funding to finish my research and provide a fix though!

Comment: That's great, @Jon G.